# Infinite loop in while

Tags: python, while-loop

I am not quite sure while this while loop is creating infinite loop.

```
def read_m_by_rating(first_year,last_year,top_number):
current_index=1
final_list=[]
while current_index <=top_number:
    url="http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&sort=user_rating&start="+str(current_index)+"&title_type=feature&year=2005,2014"
    print url
    if top_number==55:
      lis=read_m_from_url(url,top_number-current_index+1)
    else:
     lis=read_m_from_url(url,50)
final_list=lis
current_index +=50
return final_list
read_m_by_rating(2005,2015,55)
```

Comment: From the rolled back edit: _I fixed the indentation problem which I was having earlier and it works now._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your loop:

```
while current_index <=top_number:
    url="http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&sort=user_rating&start="+str(current_index)+"&title_type=feature&year=2005,2014"
    print url
    if top_number==55:
      lis=read_m_from_url(url,top_number-current_index+1)
    else:
     lis=read_m_from_url(url,50)
```

Here's the statements inside that loop which modify `current_index`:

Here's the statements inside that loop which modify `top_number`:

Note that there are no lines that modify either of those variables. Perhaps there should be?

Comment: @ Bill Lynch, current index is increased by 50 in each iteration  and top_number is 55.

Comment: @Phil2014: The code you've posted very clearly doesn't do that. Note that python uses indentation to denote when a block of code starts and ends. The line `current_index +=50` has the same indentation as `while current_index <=top_number:` so it clearly isn't inside the loop. Perhaps the code you posted in your question needs to be fixed so it looks like the code you're actually running?